# How do I put an hyperlink to another page according with his ID?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and I'm stuck in here. I want to create a hyperlink, so that when I click in the movie name, it goes to a details page, with the details on it. I already have the @HTML.ActionLink to a Details class in the controller, but now I don't know what to put in the Details class. Should I create a variable to the class Index to make comparisons?

This is the action method `Index`:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        PAPEntities db = new PAPEntities();

        MovieViewModel[] movies = db.MoviesData.Select(movie => new MovieViewModel
        {
            MovieID = movie.MovieID,
            MovieName = movie.MovieName,
            MovieDescription = movie.MovieDescription,
            MovieCategory = movie.MovieCategory,
            MovieYear = movie.MovieYear
        }).ToArray();

        return View(movies);
}
```

This is the part of the Index with the @HTML.ActionLink:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink(item.MovieName, "Details", "Movies", new { id = item.MovieID }, null)</td>
            <td>@item.MovieCategory</td>
            <td>@item.MovieYear
            <td>@item.MoviePrice</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I tried to search for it, but nothing similar appears, so I'm kinda stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `@Html.ActionLink` is meant to hit the `Details` method of the `Movies` controller, and you say that:

> I already have the @HTML.ActionLink to a Details class in the controller, but now I dont know what to put in the Details class

For that I would suggest to add a method 'Details' like this in the 'Movies' controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(string id)   // might be 'int' if your MovieId is of integer type
{
    //use LINQ to fetch the movie based on input 'id'

    //return the information with the 'details' view as you did with the 'Index' method
}
```

Hope I have got your question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using asp.net core? if so you should be using Tag Helpers

Add the following in the _ViewImports.cshtml

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Then the following in your page

```
<a id="btn" asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.MovieID">@item.MovieName</a>
```

Comment: I dont have the _ViewImports.cshtml file. I searched for it and it appears that I have to install something, what is it?

Comment: Yes sorry, install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers from nuget

Comment: yap, I did it. But the file didnt appear. Do i need to do something else?

Comment: You can just create a cshtml file, under Views. and then add the Tag Helper

@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

Comment: Here's a link if you get stuck 

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/files/viewimports

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing `class` and `method`.
The code you posted is the method `Index` on the class (I guess) `MoviesController`.
This line

```
<td>@Html.ActionLink(item.MovieName, "Details", "Movies", new { id = item.MovieID }, null)</td>
```

creates a link to the action `Details` in the controller `Movies`, passing an id to it.

So you need in your class `MoviesController` the method `Details` having a parameter called `id` to get it and use it.

```
public class MoviesController: Controller
{
    // code of other methods

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        // get details of movie with id
    }
}
```

---

Side note: if your using `ActionLink` in a view returned by the `Movies` controller, you don't need to specify the controller again so you can write

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.MovieName, "Details", new { id = item.MovieID })
```

and it will do the same.